# How to use Session in SignalR connect

Tags: signalr

In my database a user has some area permissions.
What I want to do is to add this areas into Groups of SignalR.
So, when user sign in, I get this groups from database and save in Session["groups"] and when user connect to signalR, I use this session to add in Groups.
Something like this:

```
public Task Connect()
{
    var groups = (string[])Session["groups"];
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }
}
```

How can I do this or something like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned here [SignalR Hubs - Managing groups](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs)

> You can add connections to groups and send messages to particular groups. Groups are not persisted on the server so applications are responsible for keeping track of what connections are in what groups so things like group count can be achieved.

That means that you have to provide your own structure such as a Dictionary to hold your data.

For example, a Dictionary to hold group name as the key and List of areas as values (or the other way around if it suits you best).

So for each new area of your user, first update this Dictionary and then subscribe the user to the groups that were changed.

`Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);`

Nevertheless take a look at the link above and also here [Topic based pub sub design patern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34333/Topic-based-publish-subscribe-design-pattern-imple). Do not hesitate because of the WCF on the title. Get a closer look on the way he implements the Filter class